# How to access request headers in DataSnap Server?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, datasnap

I am using Delphi XE7.  I need to access the request headers in DataSnap Server, but it does no seem to have this option.  In DataSnap REST, it is possible, because `TWebModule` is available.

This code does not work, like in REST:

```
function TServerMethods1.EchoString(Value: string): string;
var
   Module: TWebModule;
begin
  Module := GetDataSnapWebModule;
  Result := Module.Request.RemoteIP + ': ' + Value;
end;
```

Does anyone have an idea about DataSnap Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update my project for **REST**, and resolved my problem in access **Header**. With the following code:

Need declare *Web.HTTPApp* at uses

```
var
  oWebModule: TWebModule;
  sHeader: String;
begin
  oWebModule := GetDataSnapWebModule;
  sHeader := oWebModule.Request.Content;
end;
```